# Broadcast different data for different users

Tags: laravel, websocket, broadcast, pusher

I'm running a platform with a comment module. User can comment articels there and the server decides whether a user can edit or delete a comment he doesn't own based on a role system.

These flags are computed server-side and transmitted to the client on page load but now I want to broadcast newly created comments.

Now I'm facing some kind of architecture problem: When user #1 creates a comment the comment with the edit and delete flag based on user #1 is broadcasted and thus not correct if I'm user #2.

Do I have to broadcast the new comment in each user's private channel to determine the edit and delete permission for that user or is there any advantage I could take?

Answer (score 0):

The role system should be managed in the **backend**, so the broadcasting should only serve to inform that a new message has been posted (and then you can push it in your view for example), but this doesn't need to be a problem to CRUD permissions because this should be managed based on the user `id`. For example in the `authorize()` method of a [Request object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests) injected in the controller, you could do:

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to edit the message.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    /** 
    *  The next line compares if the id of the logged in user matches         
    *  the foreign `user_id` in the message object.
    */ 
    return auth()->user()->id == $this->user_id;
}
```